# less.css - set css parameter dynamically

Tags: less

I learning how to use less.css for creating dynamic css files.
I'd like to create a dynamic property in my css file and load it, for example:

```
@marginProperty : margin-left;
.top
{
   @marginProperty: 10px;
}
```

Is this possible? Doesn't seem to compile for me. Any ideas?

Comment: For the benefit of future visitors, this ([property name interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-properties)) is currently possible in Less. The code in question would work if `@marginProperty: 10px;` is modified to `@{marginProperty}: 10px;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work quite that way; you can't set a property from a variable, variables are only values of those properties. Instead of setting a variable for the property, you should use a mixin. It's tricky, not knowing exactly how you are structuring your LESS/CSS or what your goals are, but it seems like you need to think in reverse. CSS, like SQL, is declarative, so you have to describe the result from the code, instead of describing the process of getting to that result. Something like this might do it:

```
.margin(@size:10px) {
    margin-left: @size;
}

.top {
    .margin(10px);
}
```

That `.margin` mixin can be defined in one mixin file and you can `@import` it, and when you need to redefine it, substitute that mixin file for another similar one.